# HTC Rhyme - official update

Tags: updates, root-access, device-firmware

My HTC Rhyme is now on Android 2.3.5 with HTC Sense 3.5.

So, last year I've rooted a phone probably via clockworkmod and after that I've back to the unrooted.

Now, I have unrooted device but it will not give on updata a new Android 4.0

Here is official update from [HTC](http://www.htc.com/www/support/content.aspx?id=6192) but a HTC Rhyme will not upgrade to a new Android 4.0 version.

Today, because my phone a past was rooted, i'm unrooted using [this](http://theunlockr.com/2013/06/08/how-to-unroot-the-htc-rhyme/).

I can't update to Android 4.0 unrooted version.

Comment: That's one of the drawbacks of rooting: when the update checks the CRC of the installed "ROM", you've got no chance to install it (rooting manipulates `/system`, so the checksum fails). What's the error message you get? Is it an OTA update, or are you installing manually from a download? To check for alternatives, see e.g. [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)

Comment: Is it possible to update ROM using stock rom from HTC?

Comment: A "full installation" of a stock-ROM should be possible. But you will have to backup your data first, or lose them. A "differential update" will fail for above given reasons.

Comment: i was  searching how to update firmware.. and i couldn't find, so i unroot w " installing" same fw and everything went well. he booted now its time to root. i have tried almost 10 root apps  and every time my PC said its rooted but with root check "no root" i dont know what else should i try?

Comment: First congrats for solving the issue! Could you please make that an answer (like a mini-howto on what you did)? Might help future visitors! // As for the rooting question: Please, use a separate post for that, as it's a different issue.